# Do INSERTs get auto-committed?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Our application fires an INSERT query to the MySQL Database to add records. I want to know whether or not the records get auto-committed. If I run the ROLLBACK command, when does the database perform a rollback ? Is a ROLLBACK possible after a COMMIT ?

Comment: Just for clarification, I tagged is as 'innodb' 19 hours ago, since InnoDB uses COMMIT/ROLLBACK.

Comment: This gets a +1 for reminding Developers and DBAs to pay attention of transactional behavior, the correspongding application paradigms supporting transactions, and its consequences (good or bad).

Comment: I answered your question with a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on whether-or-not you're within a transaction that will span over more than one statement. (You've tagged the question with InnoDB, the answer would be different with MyISAM.)

From the reference manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html

> By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that
>   as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table,
>   MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent.

So yes, by default, if you're just using `INSERT`, the records you insert will be committed, and there is no point trying to roll them back. (This is effectively the same as wrapping each statement between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.)

However, if you're dealing with transactions explicitly, you will have to use `COMMIT` to commit store the records, but you will also be able to use `ROLLBACK`.

You can start a transaction explicitly by using `START TRANSACTION` (or `BEGIN`). This is independent of the `autocommit` setting (on by default):

> With START TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the
>   transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The autocommit mode then reverts
>   to its previous state.

Alternatively, if `autocommit=0`, I think any statement following another end of transaction, will start a transaction (but you can still use `START TRANSACTION` explicitly); that's at least the way I [interpret this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit):

> The autocommit mode. If set to 1, all changes to a table take effect
>   immediately. If set to 0, you must use COMMIT to accept a transaction
>   or ROLLBACK to cancel it. If autocommit is 0 and you change it to 1,
>   MySQL performs an automatic COMMIT of any open transaction. Another
>   way to begin a transaction is to use a START TRANSACTION or BEGIN
>   statement. See Section 12.3.1, “START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and
>   ROLLBACK Syntax”.

More specifically "another way to begin a transaction" seems to imply that setting "autocommit=0" is enough to start a transaction (at least just before each statement at the start a session or that follows a `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK`).
I would suggest to use `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION` explicitly anyway even if `autocommit=0`, as it can make it clearer to see when the transaction starts or ends.

(How you start a transaction may depend on the way your application uses MySQL.)

Comment: Deserves a +1 for fully defining transactional protocols.

Comment: @Bruno, For MyISAM where "commit" and "rollback" don't work, wouldn't the inserts be half-committed?

Answer (score 8):

By default, [**InnoDB is set to autocommit = 1 or ON**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit). *Once committed, they cannot be rolled back*.

You would have to do one of two things to disable it going forward:

OPTION 1 : Add this to /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql

```
[mysqld]
autocommit=0
```

OPTION 2 : Perform one of these in the open DB Conenction before beginning any meaningful SQL

```
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
```

Under these two options, you would have to perform a [**manual COMMIT or a manual ROLLBACK**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html).

CAVEAT

If the table is MyISAM, then the explanation is simpler. Since there are no transactions for the MyISAM storage engine, all INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs executed are permanent. No rollbacks whatsoever.

Comment: For additional clarification, my answer addresses both InnoDB and MyISAM storage engines.

Comment: Just in case Auto Commit is OFF in InnoDB and my application is firing Insert Queries, and I forget to execute the Commit, how soon are changes lost?

Comment: If your application manually fires a COMMIT after each INSERT, it is written and cannot be deleted. If the DB Connection dies before you COMMIT, all changes are lost and rollback occurs. If you perform any DDL (CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, ALTER TABLE, etc) or manually issue a table lock, the INSERTs are autocommited. If you use START TRANSACTION, all uncommited changes are committed.

Comment: Regarding "If you use START TRANSACTION, all uncommited changes are committed." (in the context of DDLs, otherwise it would be rolled back), there's also an [implicit commit before](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html) (the implicit commit after is from version 5.5.3 according to the documentation).

Comment: "If you use START TRANSACTION, all uncommited changes are committed." - I got that idea from MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide (ISBN 0-672-32812-7) Page 418 which names START TRANSACTION, SET AUTOCOMMIT=1,LOCK TABLES,UNLOCK TABLES,TRUNCATE TABLE,RENAME TABLE, DROP INDEX,DROP TABLE,DROP DATABASE,CREATE INDEX,BEGIN, and ALTER TABLE under the headings "Under some circumstances, the current transaction may end implicitly: If you issue any of the following statements, InnoDB implicitly commits the preceding uncommitted statements of the current transaction and begins a new transaction".

Comment: This means that implicit commits were around as of 5.0.18, the version of MySQL when the book was released.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA yes, that's what I way saying (probably not not clearly enough, I must admit) the implicit commits _before_ the execution of those commands were done in 5.0 (and perhaps in earlier version), not the ones _after_ their execution.

Comment: If I use START TRANSACTION and connection dies because of some reason before END TRANSACTION, will it commit or not? If yes, then is it possible to manually ROLLBACK?

Comment: No, it will rollback if the DB connection dies or times out. Make sure you have wait_timeout and interactive_timeout set as high as you need. Default value for both is 28800, which is 8 hours.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, But what if it's MyISAM where "rolling back" doesn't exist? Wouldn't the values be "half committed" as demonstrated in http://rpbouman.blogspot.sg/2007/02/mysql-transactions-and-autocommit.html ? **Also,** (back to your answer) regarding your answer's option 2, Why do you write `SET autocommit = 0; START TRANSACTION;`? Wouldn't writing `SET autocommit = 0;` do the trick?

Comment: @Pacerier The key word is MyISAM. Nothing MyISAM can ever rollback. There is nothing transactional about MyISAM. Running `SET autocommit = 0;` have absolutely no effect on MyISAM. Please look back at my CAVEAT : `If the table is MyISAM, then the explanation is simpler. Since there are no transactions for the MyISAM storage engine, all INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs executed are permanent. No rollbacks whatsoever.` I set `SET autocommit = 0; START TRANSACTION;` in Option 2 because the original question was about InnoDB.

Comment: @Pacerier I have discussed MyISAM not being able to rollback before : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25547/mysql-myisam-data-recovery-implementation/25578#25578 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68187/mysql-wrong-bytesec-0-0-0-at-linkstart-0/68192#68192

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, Regarding that, I mean even for InnoDB, `SET autocommit = 0;` already does the exact same thing as `SET autocommit = 0; START TRANSACTION;` right? Wouldn't the second part `START TRANSACTION;` be optional.

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, it is optional. I include both in the event someone wants to rollback halfway using savepoints : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/savepoint.html. In addition, if multiple statements has to be treated a single transaction and you want that transaction as a single unit for your savepoint, then both options become necessary. I just do both and leave things open-ended giving other the option to use it or not.

Comment: Is ‘autocommit mode’ a *configuration* of the database engine (e.g. PostgreSQL server)/driver (e.g. psql client), or is it a *scope* of SQL code outside of START TRANSACTION and COMMIT/ROLLBACK pairs? The [SQLite database engine](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html) seems to use the second meaning: ‘The sqlite3_get_autocommit() interface returns non-zero or zero if the given database connection is or is not in autocommit mode, respectively. Autocommit mode is on by default. Autocommit mode is disabled by a BEGIN statement. Autocommit mode is re-enabled by a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.’